# Remove bracket highlight line

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

i'd like to ask a question about SublimeText configuration. Somehow i managed to disable the dots line matching two brackets or code block.

This is what i mean [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZBu-67zVVvQlh6NEtzQ18yNmM/view?usp=sharing)

I'd like to know how to enable it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the parameter `draw_indent_guides` to `true` in the user settings. It should be the default value though, maybe one of your plugins managed to disable it?

Comment: thanks man, you get it! Probably yes one of my plugin disabled it.